# Converting a jQuery plugin into a WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

For my WordPress site I really need to be able to have the functions that [this library offers](http://fstoke.me/jquery/window/).

My question is would it be possible to convert that jQuery plugin into a working WordPress plugin? And if so, how?

Would this be the correct way to make the init.php file?

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: jQuery Windows
Plugin URI: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window
Description: Sexy jQuery Windows. 
Version: 5.03 
Author: PC - Prashant Chaudhary
Author URI: http://fstoke.me/jquery/window
License: Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 
*/
wp_enqueue_style(
    'jquerywindowstyles',
    WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/jQuery-windows/css/jquery.window.css',
    false,
    all);

// Add the scripts to the footer
function jquerywindowjs(){
    // Identify our javascript files
    wp_register_script(
        'jquery.window',
        WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/jquery-windows/jquery.window.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        "2.1.4",
        1 );
    wp_register_script(
        'jquery.window.min',
        WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/jquery-windows/jquery.window.min.js',
        array( 'jquery', 'jquery.window' ),
        "1.0",
        1 );
    // Then enqueue them
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.window' );
}
// Action our scripts
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquerywindowjs' );
?>
```

Comment: You can install this in your theme without making it into a plugin, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer is Yes, It is possible . and easily.
How to do that , is a different question and much more elaborated .
But , if you need it for a one-time-use in one site -  you always have the option to just include the script using [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), and the styles with [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)  in your `functions.php` and then use as is ..

But , you already have a lot of wordpress plugins that have similar functionality ..

see :
http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=modal

or

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=popup

It is not exluded that you can find the same script already as a plugin since there are literally hundreds of them..

Comment: I have looked for a similar plugin but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, all you do to make php/js code into a Wordpress plugin is give it the plugin header, set up a place where your code is inserted into wordpress (actions), and optionally create a configuration page for the plugin in PHP for the wordpress admin.

Basically, that would mean repackaging the current jquery plugin as a wordpress plugin. It would function as a way to install this plugin into wordpress.

WP has pretty good documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

I found that starting with a simple plugin (one php file), reading it, and seeing how it worked gave me enough info to start turning my code into WP plugins.

Comment: would you please tell me how can i add configuration page? can you suggest any tutorial?

Comment: Find a simple plugin and use the same hooks.